# Access an App Service integrated with a Virtual Network from other Azure resources

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I must have a Web API deployed inside an App Service that must be able to connect to resources located inside an on-premise environment (site-to-site connection).

For this purpose i would set up a Virtual Network with a VPN Gateway and a Local VPN Gateway properly configured (for the site-to-site part).
Then i would integrate my App Service with this VNET.

My questions are:

1) If my app service is integrated with this VNET, is it able to communicate with other PAAS resources like **Azure Storage**, **Azure SQL Database** or **Function Apps** without doing any other configuration steps or i need to do something more?

Essentially i need to understand if an App Service integrated with a VNET becomes isolated from other Azure resources that are not "part" of that VNET.

2) An Azure Function deployed into the **same** App Service can call the REST endpoints exposed by the Web API without doing any other configuration steps or i need to integrate the Function App with the same VNET?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question:

Q1: Yes, Web app integrated VNet does not impact other PAAS resources communications. VNet Integration gives your web app **access to resources in your VNet** but doesn't grant private access to your web app from the VNet. This does not mean the web app could not access other Azure resources that are not "part" of that VNET. This allows web app extra to access the resources in a VNet.

If you use service endpoint with VNet for the Azure Storage, Azure SQL Database, you could not add these integrated VNets to the firewall of these PAAS services(since they are not resources in such VNet), you could add the outbound public IP for the web app to whitelist the web app access. Now the [new Preview VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#new-vnet-integration) feature will work with ExpressRoute and Service Endpoints.

Q2: You do not need to do VNet Integration since Web API does not exist in a VNet. You could directly call it. If you are interested in requesting some resources like API deployed in a VM in some VNet. You could refer to the document [Integrate a Function App with an Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet)